# Getting the value of a foreign key of a foreign key in Django

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have three models as follows:

```
class ServiceCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def natural_key(self):
        return self.name

class Service(models.Model):
    service_category = models.ForeignKey(ServiceCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def natural_key(self):
        return self.name

class Request(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    services = models.ManyToManyField(Service)

    def natural_key(self):
        return self.name
```

I want to query with the default Django in a way that I can get the names of the Service Category since I will be filtering on it.

Currently I have the following:

```
    data = Request.objects.all()

    data = serialize("json", data, use_natural_foreign_keys=True)
```

So far I only get back the names of the services, but not the service categories. I have tried `values` but it throws an error when I serialize. I tried to add the fields argument in serialize with `services__service_category__name` and it did not work as well.

Can anyone help with this please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it with the following code in your view, it works for me:

```
def get_categories(request):
    requests = Request.objects.all()
    service_categories = []
    for request in requests:
        service_categories = request.services.values("service_category__name").all()
```

If you want to serialize the data afterwards you can't use 'values()', but you can serialize them with json.dumps (check code below)

```
import json

def get_categories(request):
    data_list = list(Request.objects.values("services__service_category__name").all())
    data = json.dumps(data_list)
```

Comment: But then how can this be used in serialize?

Comment: @aboveandbeyond Edited my solution for further serialization into json.